# Haskell : how to use "deriving Show" and functor?

Tags: haskell

Question 1:
I have the definition for a tree type:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) |Empty
```

Use the Show typeclass to implement a show function. A tree like Node 10 (Node 20 Empty (Node 6
Empty Empty)) (Node 30 Empty Empty)) should display as (10 (20 x 6) 30) . So, a node with two empty branches should not be parenthesized.

My code is as follows:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) |Empty deriving (show) 
 --input
*Main>>Node 10 (Node 20 Empty (Node 6 Empty Empty)) (Node 30 Empty Empty))
 --output
*Main>>Node 10 (Node 20 Empty (Node 6 Empty Empty)) (Node 30 Empty Empty))
```

Is there any method to change it , let the output is:

```
(10 (20 x 6) 30)
```

Question 2:

Use the functor class to define fmap for this type ?
(How can I implement above function use functor?)

Answer (score 2):

You can see how to implement `Functor` instance for `Tree` [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass).

If some type is instance of `Functor` type class it means that you can map it's value and to preserve it's context (use link above to read more about `Functor`) . For example, if you have `tree :: Tree Int` with some values in each node, than you can replace all of them by `'A'` character using `fmap (\ _ -> 'A') tree`. The result will be `Tree Char`, but it is still a `Tree`.

To print some value, you need to convert it into a `String`. Converting `tree :: Tree a` to `String` produces `String` but not a `Tree Int` anymore. That's why you can't use `fmap` to implement such conversion.

To do that, you have to traverse a `Tree a`. Only thing you can do just to use `fmap` is to convert all values to `String`s and then concatenate it in some order when traversing a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you would implement `Show`:

```
instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where
    show Empty = "()"
    show (Node x Empty Empty) = show x
    show (Node x Empty y) = "(" ++ show x ++ " x " ++ show y ++ ")"
    show (Node x Empty y) = "(" ++ show x ++ " " ++ show y ++ " x)"
    show (Node x y z) = "(" ++ show x ++ " " ++ show y ++ " " ++ show z ++ ")"
```

However, that would be a bit of an abuse of `Show`, since it’s supposed to produce output that can reconstruct the input…

http://codepad.org/CDM1v2AY

Comment: Well, that's output that can reconstruct the input - there's a one-to-one mapping between Tree a objects and their representations in his scheme. So all that's needed is a matching implementation of `Read`, right?

Comment: @amalloy: Well, if any `a` produces output with spaces and without delimiters (e.g. the default for `deriving Show`), it’ll be hard… I suppose it’d be possible to check for those and parenthesize when necessary.

Comment: I mean, you'll use the `Read` instance for `a`, which solves your problem, right? And your objection applies equally well to the default instance produced by `deriving Show`, I think, so it shouldn't be an issue.